# Solve for parameters of a system of non linear equations that have forms of $0 = e^x + A_1 e^x + A_2 e^{2x} + A_3$

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I'm self studying math and came across a problem that I have to solve for parameters of the following equations,
$$
0 = e^{-x} - A_1 - A_2 e^{-x} - A_3e^{-2x} \\
0 = e^{-2x} - A_1e^{-x} - A_2 - A_3e^{-x} \\
0 = e^{-3x} - A_1e^{-2x} - A_2e^{-x} - A_3 \\
$$
The answer given is $A_1=e^{-x}, A_2=0, A_3 = 0$, but there's no method shown for finding these.
I was thinking I can put them in matrix form but I don't think that works, any suggestion of systemically finding the solution besides substituting individually?

Comment: SInce $x$ is a constant, let $e^{-x}=k$, $e^{-2x}=k^2$, $e^{-3x}=k^3$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici interesting, I search about solving system of polynomials, and this problem seems to be more difficult than I thought.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I tried substituting with $k^n$, do you mind checking if this is valid? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3033628/235884

Comment: It is $$A_1=e^{-x},A_2=A_3=0$$