# Solve Ax=b, where A consist of $x^k$, is my method using RREF on augmented matrix valid?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have Ax=b,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & x^2 \\
x & 1 & x \\
x^2 & x & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ x^2 \\ x^3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and I transform it into an augmented matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & x & x^2 & x \\
x & 1 & x & x^2\\
x^2 & x & 1 & x^3
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}
$$

I tried to do RREF by considering x and function of x as part of constants, for example, $R_2-R_1x$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & x & x^2 & x \\
x-x & 1-x^2 & x-x^3 & x^2-x^2\\
x^2 & x & 1 & x^3
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & x & x^2 & x \\
0 & 1-x^2 & x-x^3 & 0\\
x^2 & x & 1 & x^3
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}
$$

And finally arrive at,
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & x \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}

$$ a = x, b = 0, c = 0$$

Are the operations to reduce the matrix by multiplying by x and function of x valid?

Comment: Is $x$ a constant or variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & x & x^2 & x \\
0 & 1-x^2 & x-x^3 & 0\\
x^2 & x & 1 & x^3
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_3\to R_3-x^2R_1}\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & x & x^2 & x \\
0 & 1-x^2 & x-x^3 & 0\\
0 & x(1-x^2) & 1-x^4 & 0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}\\\xrightarrow{R_3\to R_3-xR_2}\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & x & x^2 & x \\
0 & 1-x^2 & x-x^3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1-x^2 & 0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow[R_1\to R_1+R_3]{R_2\to R_2+xR_3}\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & x & 1 & x \\
0 & 1-x^2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1-x^2 & 0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}$

If $x$ is a constant and $1-x^2=0, b,c\in\Bbb R, a=x(1-b)-c=\pm(1-b)-c$.

If $x$ is a constant but $1-x^2\ne0, b=c=0,a=x\ne\pm1$.

If $x$ is a variable, then in general, $b=c=0, a=x.$

Comment: it makes sense if it's constant, but if it's variable does it make sense to do RREF still?

Comment: Yes, you can still do Gaussian Elimination, but if $x$ is a variable and $a,b,c$ are constants, you don't have a solution to the system as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

We only can divide a row by $x$ if $x\neq0$. Therefore, the case in which $x=0$ should be treated as a special case. More generaly, you can only divide a row by $f(x)$ if $f(x)\neq0$.

Comment: interesting, the x is actually representing $e^{-t_0}, t_0\geq 0$. So it seems to work in general. But there's a case where I had to divide a row by $1-x^2 = 1-e^{-2t_0}$ which is zero if $t_0 = 0 $.